# combine array and lis of tuples

Tags: python, numpy

please check this - [multiply numpy row with all elements in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693201/multiply-numpy-row-with-all-elements-in-list)

```
utl = np.array(  [[  3.  ,134.49999389648437,  134.1, -0.02]])

all_ltp = [(0, 134.30000305175778), (1, 133.80000305175778), (2, 134.14999389648438), (3, 134.39999389648438), (4, 134.30000305175778),(5, 134.14999389648438), (6, 134.19999694824222)]


a = np.array([np.hstack(tpl) for tpl in it.product(upper_trend_line, all_ltp)])
a = np.array(list(it.product(upper_trend_line, all_ltp)), dtype=object).T
a = np.hstack((np.vstack(a[0]), np.vstack(a[1])))
print(a)

output is  - 
 
[[  3.         134.4999939  134.1         -0.02         0.  134.30000305]
 [  3.         134.4999939  134.1         -0.02         1.  133.80000305]
 [  3.         134.4999939  134.1         -0.02         2.  134.1499939 ]
 [  3.         134.4999939  134.1         -0.02         3.  134.3999939 ]
 [  3.         134.4999939  134.1         -0.02         4.  134.30000305]
 [  3.         134.4999939  134.1         -0.02         5.  134.1499939 ]
 [  3.         134.4999939  134.1         -0.02         6.  134.19999695]]
```

what i want is take the 4th value from a and go to all_ltp take its next element and combine it to a  i.e

```
for kk in range(len(a)):
    if a[kk][4]+1 <len(all_ltp):
        print(a[kk], (all_ltp[int(a[kk][4]+1)]))

output is working but i want it without loop and list elements  inside the array-


[  3.    134.4999939  134.1         -0.02     0. 134.30000305] (1, 133.80000305175778)
[  3.    134.4999939  134.1         -0.02     1. 133.80000305] (2, 134.14999389648438)
[  3.    134.4999939 134.1        -0.02        2. 134.1499939] (3, 134.39999389648438)
[  3.    134.4999939 134.1        -0.02        3. 134.3999939] (4, 134.30000305175778)
[  3.    134.4999939  134.1         -0.02     4. 134.30000305] (5, 134.14999389648438)
[  3.    134.4999939 134.1        -0.02        5. 134.1499939] (6, 134.19999694824222)

expected - if possible without following the reference question answer of stacking it first 

[  3.    134.4999939  134.1         -0.02     0. 134.30000305  1  133.80000305175778] 
[  3.    134.4999939  134.1         -0.02     1. 133.80000305  2  134.14999389648438] 
[  3.    134.4999939 134.1        -0.02        2. 134.1499939  3  134.39999389648438] 
[  3.    134.4999939 134.1        -0.02        3. 134.3999939  4  134.30000305175778]
[  3.    134.4999939  134.1         -0.02     4. 134.30000305  5  134.14999389648438] 
[  3.    134.4999939 134.1        -0.02        5. 134.1499939  6  134.19999694824222]
```

Comment: Your code is missing imports and doesn't run. If I understand correctly your output is correct but not formatted to your preference. Please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Looks like you are just repeating the last 2 columns, which could be done in your original construction with `a = np.hstack((np.vstack(a[0]), np.vstack(a[1], np.vstack(a[1]))))`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to fill each row of a with its previous content concatenated (+) with what you already identified as the correct elements to "stack" (all_ltp[int(a[kk][4]+1)])

```
for kk in range(len(a)):
    if a[kk][4]+1 <len(all_ltp):
        a[kk] = [i for i in a[kk]] + all_ltp[int(a[kk][4]+1)]
        print(a[kk], (all_ltp[int(a[kk][4]+1)]))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?